# Re-Directing output to a variable for mailing purpose

Tags: powershell

I was trying to use the below mentioned piece of script to fetch the particular events from the system event logs. Now i need to redirect the output to my mail. But not sure how to re-direct this output. Can somebody help me to achieve this?

```
foreach ($server in $Servers){ 
  Write-Host "Host Name :"$Server -fore "yellow" -nonewline

  try {
    Get-WinEvent -ComputerName $Server -FilterHashtable @{logname="system"; id=1135,1038,1065,1069; StartTime="09/12/2015"} -ErrorAction Stop | fl id, LevelDisplayName, TimeCreated, ProviderName, Message
  } catch [Exception] {
    if ($_.Exception -match "No events were found that match the specified selection criteria") {
      Write-Host " :  NO EVENTS FOUND`n" -fore "Green"
    }
  }
}

$smtpServer = "smtpserver name"
$msg = new-object Net.Mail.MailMessage
$smtp = new-object Net.Mail.SmtpClient($smtpServer)

#E-mail setup
$msg.From = "roji.rajan@test.com"
$msg.To.Add("roji.rajan@test.com")
$msg.Subject = "Eventlog Report"
$msg.Body = "Hi Roji, `n 
Please find the report below.."

$smtp.Send($msg)
```

Answer (score 4):

Don't think in terms of output redirection when working with variables - you want *assignment*:

```
$myevents = Get-WinEvent
```

And the append it to your body:

```
# after first assignment to Body, but before Send()
$msg.Body += $myevents | Out-String
```